# Can't retrieve data in Google namespace from XML document with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, namespaces, nokogiri, google-shopping

I have this Google shopping feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
<channel>
  <item>
    <title>test</title>
    <g:id>1</g:id>
    <g:color>blue</g:color>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>test2</title>
    <g:id>2</g:id>
    <g:color>red</g:color>
  </item>
</channel></rss>
```

I've been searching for several days now and I can't seem to find the answer. I also worked through the Nokogiri documentation but this also didn't clear up anything.

What I am trying to do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(*Google Shopping Feed*)
doc.css('channel > item').each do |item|
  puts item.css('g:id')
end
```

But this returns nothing. I've tried a lot of suggestions but none seem to work. Clearly I am missing out on something here but I can't figure out what.

Another thing that I can't figure out is retrieving a list of all attributes in an item. So my question is how can I retrieve the following array out of the Google Shopping feed:

```
# attributes => ['title', 'g:id', 'g:color']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `at_xpath` along with `text`:

```
doc.css('channel > item').each do |item|
  puts item.at_xpath('g:id').text
end
#=> 1
#=> 2
```

> Another thing that I can't figure out is retrieving a list of all
>   attributes in an item.

You could get an array of each `item` like this:

```
doc.css('channel > item').map do |item|
  item.element_children.map do |key|
    prefix = "#{key.namespace.prefix}:" if key.namespace
    name   = key.name

    "#{prefix}#{name}"
  end
end
#=> [["title", "g:id", "g:color"], ["title", "g:id", "g:color"]]
```

If all items will have the exact same attributes, then you could just use the first element (instead of iterating all of them):

```
doc.css('channel > item').first.element_children.map do |key|
  prefix = "#{key.namespace.prefix}:" if key.namespace
  name   = key.name

  "#{prefix}#{name}"
end
#=> ["title", "g:id", "g:color"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gerry this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep namespace information, the easiest solution would probably be to use an Xpath expression.

Something along the lines of

```
doc.xpath('//item').each_with_index do |node, i|
  puts "Element #{i} attributes:"
  node.xpath("*/text()").each do |element| 
    puts "#{element.name}: #{element.text}"
  end
end
```